CUDA out of memory: How to manage large tensor (400x400)?
EDIT: Added details
I'm trying to train Neural A* algorithm(original repo)  with 400x400 maps(houses, and closed areas), and for each one I have tot couples start-goal, and the relative expected path.
I'm using a remote GPU nvidia Ampere 80 GB, but I receive the following error:
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 20.00 MiB (GPU 0; 79.17 GiB total capacity; 70.98 GiB already allocated; 15.81 MiB free; 77.41 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF

This algorithm seems to be really heavy, but do I really consume 80 GB of memory?
I tried to:

load maps with lazy loading, setting the trainer (from pytorch
lightning) precision to 16 to make it use float16 where possible
decreased the batch size
decreased the lr
decreased the depth of the encoder.
trying to set max_split_size_mb

Is there some other tip to reduce memory usage?
There is the type of image
Now, the goal train the algorithm using a start and goal location in the map choosen from the voronoi graph, which i also use to create the expected path.
This is the voronoi module:
  """
Voronoi Graph Generator, partially copied from 
https://github.com/micheleantonazzi/gibson-env-utilities/blob/main/gibson_env_utilities/
"""
import os
from typing import List, Tuple, Dict, Set, Union
import heapq
import cv2
import yaml
import numpy as np
import sys
from skimage.morphology import skeletonize
from termcolor import colored
from collections import deque
import random

from neural_astar.utils.voronoi_utilities.Graph.voronoi_graph import Coordinate, Graph, Node  
class VoronoiGraphGenerator:
    def __init__(self, cluster: str, env_name: str, floor: int):
        self._env_name = env_name
        self._floor = floor

        try:
            self._map = cv2.imread(os.path.join(os.path.dirname('/home/mastrelli/neural-astar/src/neural_astar/utils/voronoi_utilities/'), 'maps_data', 'maps', cluster, env_name + '_floor_' + str(floor) + '.jpg'))
            with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname('/home/mastrelli/neural-astar/src/neural_astar/utils/voronoi_utilities/'), 'maps_data', 'maps_metadata', env_name + '_floor_' + str(floor)) + '.yaml', mode='r') as f:
                map_metadata: Dict = yaml.load(f, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
            self._scale = map_metadata['scale']
            self._map_origin = Coordinate(x=map_metadata['origin']['x'], y=map_metadata['origin']['y'],
                                          map_origin=(map_metadata['origin']['x'], map_metadata['origin']['y']), scale=self._scale)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print(colored(
                'The map or its metadata of the {0} world do not exist! Create them before using this VoronoiGraphGenerator'.format(
                    env_name), 'red'))
            raise FileNotFoundError

        self._map: np.array = cv2.cvtColor(self._map, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
        self._voronoi_bitmap = np.array([], dtype=int)

        # Graph structure
        # Contains the black point of the voronoi bitmap (which are all graph nodes)
        self._graph = Graph(self._map.shape[0], self._map.shape[1], self._map_origin, self._scale)

    def _generate_voronoi_graph(self, voronoi_bitmap) -> Graph:
        """
        Extracts the graph from voronoi bitmap.
        The graph can be composed by multiple connected components, the graph entity stores all of them.
        Typically the robot positions are chosen from the longest one.
        The side lines are pruned directly by the graph.
        :return: the graph
        """

        graph = Graph(self._map.shape[0], self._map.shape[1], self._map_origin, self._scale)
        # Creates graph nodes converting black pixels
        for y, x in np.ndindex(voronoi_bitmap.shape[:2]):
            # If the pixel is black, it represents a graph node
            if voronoi_bitmap[y, x] == 0:
                node = Node(Coordinate(x=x, y=y, map_origin=(self._map_origin.x, self._map_origin.y), scale=self._scale))
                graph.add_node(node)

        # Search connection between nodes
        # Two nodes are connected it their image coordinates are adjacent
        # For each node, its surroundings is checked to find other black pixels (that are connected nodes).
        nodes = graph.get_nodes()
        for node in nodes.values():
            y, x = node.get_coordinate().to_img_index()
            mask_indexes = [(y1, x1)
                            for y1 in range(max(0, y - 1), min(y + 2, voronoi_bitmap.shape[0]))
                            for x1 in range(max(0, x - 1), min(x + 2, voronoi_bitmap.shape[1]))
                            if x1 != x or y1 != y]

            for y1, x1 in mask_indexes:
                if voronoi_bitmap[y1, x1] == 0:
                    graph.add_connection(node1_coordinates=Coordinate(x=x, y=y, map_origin=self._map_origin.get_x_y_tuple(), scale=self._scale),
                                         node2_coordinates=Coordinate(x=x1, y=y1, map_origin=self._map_origin.get_x_y_tuple(), scale=self._scale))

        graph.find_connected_components()
        return graph

    def get_voronoi_graph(self) -> Graph:
        return self._graph

    def generate_voronoi_bitmap(self, save_to_file: bool = False) -> np.array:
        """
        This method generates a voronoi bitmap starting from a floor map.
        Steps:
            1) a thresholding procedure is applied to the original floor map (the values between 0 and 250 are turned to 0)
            2) then the resulting image is eroded and dilated
            3) the resulting image is processed to find the contours
            4) the building's outline is identified (searching the longest contour)
            5) the external area of the building's contour is black filled
            6) the contour inside the building's outline are drawn and black filled
               (now the floor plan is black outside the building and over the obstacles)
            7) using these simplified contours, it is calculated the voronoi diagram
            8) the segments of the voronoi facets perimeter are examined.
               They are drawn only if they are inside the building's outline and not overlap an obstacle
               (in other words, if the extreme points that define a segment are inside the image and the correspondent pixel is white)
            9) The voronoi bitmap is used to create the graph, which finds the connected components and prunes the side lines
            10) To remove other imperfection, the voronoi bitmap generated by the graph is dilated and its skeleton
                is found using scikit-image. The old graph is replaced with a new one generated using the skeletonized voronoi bitmap
        :return: the voronoi bitmap
        """
        # 1) Threshold map
        ret, threshed_image = cv2.threshold(self._map, 250, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
        # cv2.imshow('thresh image', threshed_image)
        # cv2.waitKey(0)

        # 2) Map erosion and dilation
        eroded_image = cv2.erode(threshed_image, np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8), borderType=cv2.BORDER_REFLECT)
        # cv2.imshow('eroded image', threshed_image)
        # cv2.waitKey(0)

        dilated_image = cv2.dilate(eroded_image, np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8))
        # cv2.imshow('dilate image', threshed_image)
        # cv2.waitKey(0)

        # 3) Find contours
        (image_width, image_height) = dilated_image.shape
        contour_image = np.array([0 for _ in range(image_width * image_height)], dtype='uint8').reshape(
            (image_width, image_height))
        contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilated_image, mode=cv2.RETR_TREE, method=cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

        # 4) Find the building contour (it is assumed to be the longest one)
        l_contour_index, l_contour = max(enumerate(contours[1:]), key=lambda v: cv2.arcLength(v[1], closed=True))
        l_contour_index += 1

        #  5) Fill the area outside the building's contour
        cv2.drawContours(contour_image, contours, contourIdx=l_contour_index, color=255, thickness=cv2.FILLED)
        # cv2.imshow('external contour image', contour_image)
        # cv2.waitKey(0)

        # 6) Draw only contours inside the longest one and fill them (hierarchy = [Next, Previous, First_Child, Parent])
        filled_image = contour_image.copy()
        enumerate_hierarchy = list(enumerate(hierarchy[0]))

        def draw_internal_contours(e_hierarchy: Tuple[int, List]):
            index = e_hierarchy[0]
            hierarchy_data = e_hierarchy[1]

            # Draw and fill contour
            cv2.drawContours(filled_image, [contours[index]], contourIdx=-1, color=0, thickness=cv2.FILLED)

            # If this contour has a next one at the same hierarchy level
            if hierarchy_data[0] != -1:
                draw_internal_contours(enumerate_hierarchy[hierarchy_data[0]])

            # If this contour has a child
            if hierarchy_data[2] != -1:
                draw_internal_contours(enumerate_hierarchy[hierarchy_data[2]])

        # Get first child of the external contour and all the internal contours are drawn and black filled
        first_child = hierarchy[0][l_contour_index][2]
        if first_child != -1:
            draw_internal_contours(enumerate_hierarchy[first_child])
        # cv2.imshow('filled image', filled_image)
        # cv2.waitKey(0)

        # 7) The voronoi diagram is calculated using Delaunay triangulation
        rect = (0, 0, self._map.shape[1], self._map.shape[0])
        subdiv = cv2.Subdiv2D(rect)

        for contour, contour_hierarchy in zip(contours, hierarchy[0]):
            # Insert the all contours' points into subdiv
            for point in [np.array(p[0], dtype=float) for p in contour]:
                subdiv.insert(point)

        # 8) Draw voronoi facets contours and create the voronoi bitmap
        eroded_filled_map = cv2.erode(filled_image, kernel=np.ones((3, 3), dtype=int), iterations=1)
        # cv2.imshow('eroded filled', eroded_filled_map)
        # cv2.waitKey()
        voronoi_bitmap = np.array([255 for _ in range(image_width * image_height)], dtype=np.uint8).reshape(
            (image_width, image_height))
        (facets, centers) = subdiv.getVoronoiFacetList([])

        for facet in facets:
            facet_points = np.array(facet, int)

            # Draw voronoi facets contour lines only if they are inside image boundaries
            facet_lines = zip(np.roll(facet_points, 1, axis=0), facet_points)

            for p1, p2 in facet_lines:
                if 0 <= p1[0] < contour_image.shape[1] and 0 <= p1[1] < contour_image.shape[0] and \
                        0 <= p2[0] < contour_image.shape[1] and 0 <= p2[1] < contour_image.shape[0] \
                        and eroded_filled_map[p1[1], p1[0]] > 0 and eroded_filled_map[p2[1], p2[0]] > 0:
                    cv2.line(voronoi_bitmap, p1, p2, color=0, thickness=1)

        # cv2.imshow('voronoi bitmap', voronoi_bitmap)
        # cv2.waitKey()

        # 9) Create the voronoi graph
        graph = self._generate_voronoi_graph(voronoi_bitmap)
        graph.prune_side_lines()
        voronoi_bitmap = graph.get_graph_bitmap()

        # 10) Generate the skeletonized voronoi bitmap and replace graph
        dilated_voronoi_bitmap = cv2.bitwise_not(voronoi_bitmap)
        dilated_voronoi_bitmap = cv2.dilate(dilated_voronoi_bitmap, kernel=np.ones((3, 3), dtype=int),
                                            borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
        # cv2.imshow('dilated voronoi bitmap', dilated_voronoi_bitmap)
        # cv2.waitKey()

        dilated_voronoi_bitmap[dilated_voronoi_bitmap == 255] = 1
        skeletonized_voronoi_bitmap = cv2.bitwise_not((skeletonize(dilated_voronoi_bitmap) * 255).astype(np.uint8))
        # cv2.imshow('skeletonized voronoi bitmap', skeletonized_voronoi_bitmap)
        # cv2.waitKey()
        self._graph = self._generate_voronoi_graph(skeletonized_voronoi_bitmap)
        #self._graph.prune_side_lines()
        self._voronoi_bitmap = self._graph.get_graph_bitmap()

        if save_to_file:
            # Save voronoi bitmap
            cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(
                os.path.dirname('/home/sam/Desktop/Tesi/neural-astar/src/neural_astar/utils/voronoi_utilities/'), 'maps_data', 'voronoi_bitmaps',
                self._env_name + '_floor_' + str(self._floor) + '.png'),
                self._voronoi_bitmap)

            # Save map + voronoi bitmap
            map_voronoi_bitmap = self._map.copy()
            map_voronoi_bitmap[self._voronoi_bitmap == 0] = 0
            cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(
                os.path.dirname('/home/sam/Desktop/Tesi/neural-astar/src/neural_astar/utils/voronoi_utilities/'), 'maps_data', 'maps_with_voronoi_bitmaps',
                self._env_name + '_floor_' +  str(self._floor) + '.png'),
                map_voronoi_bitmap)

        return self._voronoi_bitmap

    def get_map(self) -> np.array:
        return self._map
    
    def get_reachable_nodes(self, start_node: Node) -> List[Node]:
        '''
        This method returns a list of all reachable nodes starting from
        start_node
        '''
        visited = set()
        queue = deque([start_node])
        reachable_nodes = []

        while queue:
            current_node = queue.popleft()
            if current_node in visited:
                continue
            visited.add(current_node)
            reachable_nodes.append(current_node)
            for neighbor in current_node.get_connected_nodes():
                if neighbor not in visited:
                    queue.append(neighbor)
        return [node for node in reachable_nodes if (self.dist_between(start_node, node)) >= 20]
                    
    def select_reachable_nodes(self) -> List[Tuple[Node, Node]]:
        '''
        This method provides a tuple of nodes, start and goal nodes.
        The start is choosen randomly and the goal ramdomly within the reachable nodes
        '''
        nodes = list(self._graph.get_nodes().values())
        lenght = len(self._graph.get_nodes())
        couples = 5

        result: List[Tuple[Node, Node]] = []
       
        while (couples > 0):
            random_start_node = random.choice(nodes)
            reachable_nodes = self.get_reachable_nodes(random_start_node)
            couples -= 1
            if(len(reachable_nodes) == 0): 
                nodes.remove(random_start_node)
                couples += 1
                continue
            random_end_node = random.choice(reachable_nodes)
           
            result.append((random_start_node, random_end_node))
                
            


        return result

    def find_shortest_path(self, start: Node, end: Node) -> Tuple[List[Node], np.array] :
        '''
        This methods is able to find the path between start and end(goal),
        using A * algorithm and using method dist_between ad heuristic 
        '''
        graph = self._graph
        open_set = []
        heapq.heappush(open_set, (0.0, start))
        came_from = {}
        g_score = {node: float('inf') for node in graph.get_nodes().values()}
        g_score[start] = 0
        f_score = {node: float('inf') for node in graph.get_nodes().values()}
        f_score[start] = self.dist_between(start, end)
        histories = np.zeros(self._map.shape)

        while open_set:
            current = heapq.heappop(open_set)[1]
            histories += self.to_numpy_array([current])

            if current == end:
                return self.reconstruct_path(came_from, current), histories
            

            for neighbor in current.get_connected_nodes():
                tentative_g_score = g_score[current] + 1
                if tentative_g_score < g_score[neighbor]:
                    came_from[neighbor] = current
                    g_score[neighbor] = tentative_g_score
                    f_score[neighbor] = tentative_g_score + self.dist_between(neighbor, end)
                    if neighbor not in [i[1] for i in open_set]:
                        heapq.heappush(open_set, (f_score[neighbor], neighbor))

        return [], histories


    def dist_between(self, a: Node, b: Node) -> float:
        '''
        As heuristic distance between two nodes, we use the euclidean norm of Numpy
        '''
        return np.linalg.norm(np.array(a.get_coordinate().get_x_y_tuple()) - np.array(b.get_coordinate().get_x_y_tuple()))

    def reconstruct_path(self, came_from: Dict[Node, Node], current: Node) -> List[Node]:
        total_path = [current]
        while current in came_from:
            current = came_from[current]
            total_path.append(current)
        total_path.reverse()
        return total_path

    def draw_path_on_bitmap(self, path: List[Node]) -> np.array:
        path_bitmap = self._voronoi_bitmap.copy()
        for i in range(len(path) - 1):
            x, y = path[i].get_coordinate().get_x_y_tuple()
            x1, y1 = path[i + 1].get_coordinate().get_x_y_tuple()
            cv2.line(path_bitmap, (x, y), (x1, y1), color=0, thickness=2)
        return path_bitmap
    
    def to_numpy_array(self, st: List[Node]) -> np.array:
        array = np.full(self._map.shape, 0, dtype=int)
        for node in st:
            x,y = node.get_coordinate().get_x_y_tuple()
            array[x, y] = 1
        return array
    

Then after building the dataset in npz files composed by:

map_design, tensor representing the map (1 for passable location, 0 otherwise)
start_maps, a all 0 tensor except for the start point
goal_maps
Excpeted path

This is how the algorithm works:

There is the code for the encoder i use:
class CNN(EncoderBase):

    CHANNELS = [32, 64, 128, 256]

    def construct_encoder(self, input_dim: int, encoder_depth: int) -> nn.Module:
"""
Simple CNN encoder

Args:
    input_dim (int): input dimension
    encoder_depth (int, optional): depth of the encoder.
"""
channels = [input_dim] + self.CHANNELS[:encoder_depth] + [1]
blocks = []
for i in range(len(channels) - 1):
    blocks.append(nn.Conv2d(channels[i], channels[i + 1], 3, 1, 1))
    blocks.append(nn.BatchNorm2d(channels[i + 1]))
    blocks.append(nn.ReLU())
return nn.Sequential(*blocks[:-1])

I think the heaviest module is the differetiable astar one. The forward pass:
 def forward(
        self,
        cost_maps: torch.tensor,
        start_maps: torch.tensor,
        goal_maps: torch.tensor,
        obstacles_maps: torch.tensor,
        store_intermediate_results: bool = False,
    ) -> AstarOutput:
        """
        Perform differentiable A* search

        Args:
            cost_maps (torch.tensor): cost maps
            start_maps (torch.tensor): start maps indicating the start location with one-hot binary map
            goal_maps (torch.tensor): goal maps indicating the goal location with one-hot binary map
            obstacle_maps (torch.tensor): binary maps indicating obstacle locations
            store_intermediate_results (bool, optional): If the intermediate search results are stored in Astar output. Defaults to False.

        Returns:
            AstarOutput: search histories and solution paths, and optionally intermediate search results.
        """

        assert cost_maps.ndim == 4
        assert start_maps.ndim == 4
        assert goal_maps.ndim == 4
        assert obstacles_maps.ndim == 4

        cost_maps = cost_maps[:, 0]
        start_maps = start_maps[:, 0]
        goal_maps = goal_maps[:, 0]
        obstacles_maps = obstacles_maps[:, 0]


        num_samples = start_maps.shape[0]
        neighbor_filter = self.neighbor_filter
        neighbor_filter = torch.repeat_interleave(neighbor_filter, num_samples, 0)
        size = start_maps.shape[-1]

        open_maps = start_maps
        histories = torch.zeros_like(start_maps)
        intermediate_results = []

        h = self.get_heuristic(goal_maps)
        h = h + cost_maps 
        g = torch.zeros_like(start_maps)

        parents = (
            #Vettori dei starting point
            torch.ones_like(start_maps).reshape(num_samples, -1)
            * goal_maps.reshape(num_samples, -1).max(-1, keepdim=True)[-1] #vettori dei goal, poi gli indici di essi
        )
 

        size = cost_maps.shape[-1]
        Tmax = self.Tmax if self.training else 1.0
        Tmax = int(Tmax * size * size)
        for t in range(Tmax):

            # select the node that minimizes cost
            f = self.g_ratio * g + (1 - self.g_ratio) * h #f di a start con ratio tra g e h
            f_exp = torch.exp(-1 * f / math.sqrt(cost_maps.shape[-1])) #attivazione di hubara, con temperatura come radice della dimensione -1 dei costi [width]

            f_exp = f_exp * open_maps #Scherma con i nodi aperti
            selected_node_maps = _st_softmax_noexp(f_exp) #Selezione nodo migliore

            if store_intermediate_results:
                intermediate_results.append(
                    {
                        "histories": histories.unsqueeze(1).detach(),
                        "paths": selected_node_maps.unsqueeze(1).detach(),
                    }
                )

            # break if arriving at the goal
            dist_to_goal = (selected_node_maps * goal_maps).sum((1, 2), keepdim=True)
            is_unsolved = (dist_to_goal < 1e-8).float()

            histories = histories + selected_node_maps
            histories = torch.clamp(histories, 0, 1) #Min 0, max 1
            open_maps = open_maps - is_unsolved * selected_node_maps
            open_maps = torch.clamp(open_maps, 0, 1)

            # open neighboring nodes, add them to the openlist if they satisfy certain requirements
            neighbor_nodes = expand(selected_node_maps, neighbor_filter)
            neighbor_nodes = neighbor_nodes * obstacles_maps

            # update g if one of the following conditions is met
            # 1) neighbor is not in the close list (1 - histories) nor in the open list (1 - open_maps)
            # 2) neighbor is in the open list but g < g2
            g2 = expand((g + cost_maps) * selected_node_maps, neighbor_filter)
            idx = (1 - open_maps) * (1 - histories) + open_maps * (g > g2)
            idx = idx * neighbor_nodes
            idx = idx.detach()
            g = g2 * idx + g * (1 - idx)
            g = g.detach()

            # update open maps
            open_maps = torch.clamp(open_maps + idx, 0, 1)
            open_maps = open_maps.detach()
 
            # for backtracking
            idx = idx.reshape(num_samples, -1)
            snm = selected_node_maps.reshape(num_samples, -1)
            new_parents = snm.max(-1, keepdim=True)[1]
    
            parents = new_parents * idx + parents * (1 - idx)


            if torch.all(is_unsolved.flatten() == 0):
                break

        # backtracking
        path_maps = backtrack(start_maps, goal_maps, parents, t)

        if store_intermediate_results:
            intermediate_results.append(
                {
                    "histories": histories.unsqueeze(1).detach(),
                    "paths": path_maps.unsqueeze(1).detach(),
                }
            )

        return AstarOutput(
            histories.unsqueeze(1), path_maps.unsqueeze(1), intermediate_results
        )


A 400x400 array of float32s is just 640KB, which is barely anything for that GPU. You’ll have to be more specific about what your algorithm is and what you are putting in the GPU memory.

I guess it's got something to do with the PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF. Did you set it somehow yet?

Perhaps the same as here (max_split_size_mb)

@nneonneo I provided some details. I have reduced the number of the images to a small number, and for each one there are 4 4d tensor: the map design, the start map, the goal map and the expected path.

@Pieterjan i did it trying to solve this problem, but didnt work

In the original paper, they are able to infer on 256x256 images with a 16GB GPU. Can you try to just infer on a 256x256 and a 400x400 test images to see how much memory you code allocates for that ? Can you also specifiy whether you allocated memory starts low and ramps up with every epoch until if fails or if it fails at the very beginning of the training ? I also see a call to a backtrack function in your code, can you explain what it does ? Backtracking can have exponential complexity in some problems

@trialNerror The backtrack function is used to calculate the path map. It doesnt even goes beyond 0% of the first epoch,even with batch_size = 1. With 1 bacth size a 400x400 image, along with the start maps and the goal maps allocates 3 mgeabyte circa in total, using torch.no_grad() obviously. Without nograd it allocates 887 megabyte.

I think WebODM also calls on Asus CUDA and is also written in Python

Ok the problem were in a loop in the differentiable astar module. Didnt change the Tmax parameter, which set how much the algorithm explore. by lowering it it worked.
